# How to extend dynamic c# object in javascript extend style?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, expandoobject

** This is a self answered question because I have found the solution but I did not find it here **

### Use case

Non well-defined structured data from **Application A** (C# Back-end) has to be passed to **Application B** (ASP.Net C# application which SignalR Front-end) using HTTP that will simply deliver the message using SignalR to the javascript clients.

The data is used as for logging in real-time.

**Why not creating classes?**
Because the data passed in can change, has not to be analyzed by the Application B, and the code of each class can't be shared between the two ends (C# / JavaScript).

Plus, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var foo = DynamicExtend(
    new { propExtendedFromDynamic1 = true }, 
    new { propExtendedFromDynamic2 = true }
);
string jsonText = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
dynamic unserializedFoo = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use expando object

Because dynamic object cannot be modified easily, the use of ExpandoObject is needed.

The only drawbacks is that it cannot complete a original dynamic object with properties of others dynamic and still use the same reference as `$.extend(true, {p1:1},{p2:2})` would do (if you know jQuery you'll understand).

```
public static dynamic DynamicExtend(params dynamic[] extendedItems)
{
        if (extendedItems == null || extendedItems.Length == 0 || extendedItems[0] == null)
            throw new Exception("Missing initial dynamic property");

        if (extendedItems.Length == 1)
            return extendedItems.First();

        dynamic r = new ExpandoObject();
        // We will need that casted value or the r[propertyName]="someValue" will fail
        var dynamicReturnedEditable = (IDictionary<string, object>)r;

        // For each dynamic object passed in
        foreach (dynamic extensionHolder in extendedItems)
        {
            var expandoCase = extensionHolder as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (expandoCase == null)
            {
                // Pour chaque propriété
                foreach (var property in ((object)extensionHolder).GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    // Faire la copie sur l'ExpandoObject (qui gère nativement le rajout de propriété) en utilisant les données extraites de l'objet dynamique
                    dynamicReturnedEditable[property.Name] = property.GetValue(extensionHolder, null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var propertyName in expandoCase.Keys)
                {
                    // Faire la copie sur l'ExpandoObject (qui gère nativement le rajout de propriété) en utilisant les données extraites de l'objet dynamique
                    dynamicReturnedEditable[propertyName] = expandoCase[propertyName];
                }
            }
        }

        return r;
}
```

Note: it does not support parameters resulting from `JObject.Parse(jsonText);` for example, because it would have to read properties from it.